# Jquery hide dropdown when mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a navigation bar with dropdown as follows.

Can I make it so when my pointer leave the navbar menu and dropdown, the dropdown get hidden? I tried `hover`, `mouseenter`, and `mouseleave` but since I don't really understand the difference and I'm new in this I got stuck.

Any help appreciated. :)

```js
$(".navbar-menu-each, .submenu-dropdown").hover(function() {
  var menuChoice = $(this).val();
  var menuPosition = $(this).find("a").position();
  var dropdownPosition = menuPosition.left;
  switch(menuChoice) {
    case 0: 
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>");
      break;
    case 1:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>");
      break;
    case 2:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download & Upload</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>");
      break;
    case 3:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>");
      break;
    case 4:
      $(".submenu-dropdown").html("<li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li><li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>");
      break;
  }
  var dropdownWidth = $(".submenu-dropdown").width();
  var rightEdge = $(document).width();
  if ((dropdownPosition + dropdownWidth) >= (rightEdge - 16)) {
    var adjustRight = rightEdge - dropdownWidth - 16;
     $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": adjustRight + "px"});
  }
  else {
    if (dropdownPosition <= 16) {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": "16px"});
    }
    else {
      $(".submenu-dropdown").css({"left": dropdownPosition + "px"}); 
    }
  }
  $(".submenu-dropdown").show();
});

$(".navbar-menu-each").click(function() {
  $(".navbar-menu-each").removeClass("menu-on");
  $(this).addClass("menu-on");
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 240px;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-top-left {

}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {

}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
}
.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 24px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each menu-on" value=0><a href="#">Employee Directory</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=1><a href="#">Memo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=2><a href="#">Bulk Update</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=3><a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a></li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each" value=4><a href="#">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="submenu-dropdown">
  
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "menuPosition is undefined". There are no a tags inside `.submenu-dropdown`

Comment: Why have you taken such a complicated route? wouldn't it be easier to have the html defined in the `html` and simply toggle visibility with javascript on hover?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are overcomplicating a simple process.

`hover` functionality can quite easily be replicated using only CSS.

```css
.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover{
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navbar-menu">
  <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
    <li class="navbar-menu-each">
      <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
      <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-each">
      <a href="#">Memo</a>
      <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
      <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download & Upload</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-each">
      <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
      <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-menu-each">
      <a href="#">Report</a>
      <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
        <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The dropdown fell under the `navbar-page-name` div though.. And also I made dropdown placement function on the jquery to make the dropdown doesn't fall outside the window (you can see on my question snippet) and it doesn't work with your method.. Sorry. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: This isn't my way, it's just the right way. Design and positioning should be handled with CSS and yes there is always a way to achieve what you want.